# react-highcharts: canvas size changes when changing tabs

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

**Description**

I have a Highcharts line chart in a "progress" tab (the tab is a react-bootstrap Tab). When I open the "progress" tab, the chart appears at 100% width, which is good. When I toggle to a different tab, then come back to the "progress" tab, the chart's width changes from 100% to a fixed 600px. I went through the docs, both the official Highcharts and React-Highcharts, and could not find a solution.

I imagine there is a problem with the re-render of the component.

**Code**

highchart-line.js:

```
export default class HighChartLine extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { config: undefined };  // or use null
    }

    getScoreData(eqId){

        const self = this;
        let url = 'src/data/dermatology/user_scores-eq' + eqId + ".json";
        axios.get(url)
            .then((response) => {
                ... //response informs
                let config = {...};

                self.setState({ config: config });
            });
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.getScoreData(this.props.equation.eqId);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.getScoreData(nextProps.equation.eqId);
    }

    render(){
    // Handle case where the response is not here yet
    if ( !this.state.config ) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    if ( this.state.config.length === 0 ) {
        return <div>Sorry, no data was found for this equation.</div>;
    }  return (
            <ReactHighcharts config={this.state.config}  />
        )
    }
}
```

highchart-line gets imported into progress-tab.js:

```
const ProgressTab = ({equation, user}) => {
    return(
            <HighChartLine equation={equation} user={user} />
  )
}; export default ProgressTab;
```

progress-tab gets imported into modal-main.js:

```
export default class ModalMain extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tabKey: this.props.tabKey
        };
    }
    handleSelect = (tabKey) => {
        this.setState({ tabKey: tabKey });
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <Tabs activeKey={this.state.tabKey}
                        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
            >
                <Tab tabClassName="main-tab" eventKey={"progress"} >
                    <ProgressTab {...this.props} />
                </Tab>
                <Tab tabClassName="main-tab" eventKey={"peer-compare"}>
                    <PeerCompareTab {...this.props}/>
                </Tab>
            </Tabs>
        )
    }
}
```

**Browser render**

Width is correctly set to 100%
[image: Width is correctly set to 100%]

Width changes itself to 600px
[image: Width changes itself to 600px]

Comment: Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle? If chart doesn't have the required size or is not correctly fitted, then you could use [`chart.reflow()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow)

Comment: I am having the exact same issue! I found if you resize the window it resizes correctly within the tab (like you, the first tab's chart is fine, but the other tabs are effectively shorter). This is annoying because I want it to make all charts the same width in all tabs without having to manually resize anything. I will work on the above commentor's suggestion and test it out...

Answer (score 0):

Although this could hurt performance somewhat, I found that if I do not pass in the `isPureConfig={true}` prop into the ReactHighcharts component, it will re-render on tab select. Being that ReactHighcharts sets `isPureConfig={false}` by default and Highcharts itself reflows by default, it will all resize accordingly. The downside is you have to work with your charts re-rendering every time: https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts#limiting-highchart-rerenders

Of course, I am not certain it's any better to reflow the chart on every tab select anyway...